# If statement and variable set from browser message boxes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, messagebox

I have a simple script to send emails. The script prompts the user to enter their name, then each email is displayed in a message box and the user is prompted to confirm whether or not the email should be sent. If the user clicks "no", the email should not be sent.

Currently, the if-statements are not working properly, the email sends regardless of msgbox response.

I think it may be the value set by the message box for the variable called "confirm". It appears the confirm variable is somehow always set to "yes" even if you click no, not sure why.

EDIT: updated to working version.

```
function sendEmails1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Send-Emails 1"));
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:D10");
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var sender = Browser.inputBox('Sender Name', 'Please enter your first and 
  last name', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

if(sender !='cancel'){
   for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var emailAddress = rowData[1];
    var recipient = rowData[2];
    var text1 = 'text';
    var text2 = 'text';
    var text3 = 'text';
    var text4 = 'text';
    var text5 = 'text';
    var signoff = 'Kind Regards,';
    var sendername = sender ;
    var org = 'text'; ; 
    var message = recipient + ',\n\n' + text1 + ' ' + text2 + ' ' + text3 + '\n\n' + text4 + '\n\n' + text5 + '\n\n' + signoff + '\n\n' + sendername + '\n\n' + org;
    var subject = 'text';

    //prompt the user with the composed email for review
    var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Send the following email?', 'To: ' + 
        emailAddress + '\\n\\n' + recipient + ',\\n\\n' + message, 
    Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
    if(confirm==='yes'){
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement should use comparison  `==` or `===`.

It should be

```
if (confirm === 'yes')
```

Comment: Aye, thanks. sender =   confirm ===    works. The sender variable confuses me a bit, I'm guessing it is setting the variable equal to the name and an ok? For some reason a == and === won't work for the sender variable.

Comment: That is because `sender` holds the input text - not the button text. See the documentation of `inputBox`

Comment: If I set the if statement to sender =, the sender variable holds the button 'ok', while sender ==, it holds the input string. This is a bit confusing, why is the if statement setting the variable value and not the variable as first defined? Google's documentation on inputbox has almost no info, its a bit frustrating.

Comment: `if (sender = 'ok')` - You are assigning the value `ok` to `sender` variable within the `if` statement here. `if (sender === 'user input')` - you compare the string "user input" with the value of `sender`. No assignment happens here.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to proceed if the button press was "ok" using the if statement, I should be checking if the inputbox button = OK, which leaves the sender variable with the input string. Is that right?

Comment: setting the if statement to if(sender == 'ok') halts the script, I guessing because sender is holding a  string rather than 'ok'

Comment: sender will never hold "Ok". Please refer the docs. Also the if statement will not halt the script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163943/discussion-between-arlen-spexarth-and-charlie-h).